# PHP "if" condition issues

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to set up a if condition whereby if $flag < 1 an apologize.php will be rendered. However it seems that the condition will be triggered even when $flag>1.Does anyone know the problem?

This is my php code.

```
$flag = query("SELECT flag FROM friend WHERE id = ? AND username = ? ",$_SESSION["id"],$username[0]["username"]);



if($flag[0]["flag"] < 1 ||$flag = false); 
{
 apologize("Sorry! He/she is not your friend.");
}
```

This is my code for the function query()

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }

    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In conditions you have to use `==` or `===`, but not `=`

Comment: Or better yet, `===`, unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @PehQinCheng - `<` or `>` may be used single, because they mean `smaller/bigger, but NOT equal`

Comment: @MarcAudet Assignments "return" the value assigned, not its success. This is why you can write `$a = $b = "derp"` and the string is assigned to both variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two fold

First off you have a `;` at the end of your if statement.

Second off you are setting `$flag = false` instead of comparing it `$flag == false`.  You probably want to compare it using the `==` equality operator.

Answer (score 0):

`$flag = false` should be `$flag == false`, `!$flag` or `$flag === false`, and ideally should be before you attempt to access it as an array:

```
if( !$flag || $flag[0]['flag'] < 1)
```

Also you have an extra `;` - this is actually the exact reason why I obstinately refuse to put a newline before `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `=` as operator, because it return `true` if it can set the variable to `false`.
Use `==`.

Comment: Assignments "return" the value assigned, not its success.

Comment: But if he set a variable to `false`, he don't get `false`.

Comment: That's because of the extra `;`